# Remote listening of an event in Javascript

Tags: javascript, listener, dom-events

I have 2 js pages, A and B.
Is there a way to trigger an event on page A and have it listened on page B ?
I miss something in my understanding to know how to do that.

Comment: What do you mean by two js pages? Frames? Pop-up? Showing some code of what you have already done might help.

Answer (score 0):

In general you can't do that directly. The pages cannot communicate, they might not be displayed in the same browser or on the same machine. For security reasons Javascript can only listen to event on the current page, change the current page and communicate to the server that the page was loaded from.

So you can listen to events on the same page, and you can trigger communication with the server based on such an event.

The server can then communicate to the other page. This can be done for example by using websockets.

Comment: FYI, all of the above is not completely true. You can make calls to other servers using JSONP which is not bound by Same origin policy.